# How to use Intersection Observer instead of window.onscroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I have the current JS for a modification to the navbar and a scroll-to-top button:

```
const navbar = document.querySelector('nav');
const scrolltotop = document.querySelector('.scrolltotop');
window.onscroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 300 && window.scrollY < 600) {
        navbar.classList.add('nav-active');
    } else if (window.scrollY > 600) {
        scrolltotop.classList.add('scrolltotop-active');
        navbar.classList.add('nav-active');
    } else {
        scrolltotop.classList.remove('scrolltotop-active');
        navbar.classList.remove('nav-active');
    }
};
```

Now I have found out about performance issue with window.onscroll method and that you should the "Intersection Observer" instead but I cannot figure out how to do it.
This is my current status:

```
const navbars = document.querySelector('nav');
const scrolltotops = document.querySelector('.scrolltotop');
const config = {
  rootMargin: '0px'
};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      intersectionHandler(entry); 
    }
  });
}, config);

navbars.forEach(navbar => {
  observer.observe(navbar);
});
function intersectionHandler(entry) {
  const id = entry.target.id;
  const currentlyActive = document.querySelector('nav.nav-active');
  const shouldBeActive = document.querySelector('nav');

  if (currentlyActive) {
    currentlyActive.classList.remove('nav-active');
  }
  if (shouldBeActive) {
    shouldBeActive.classList.add('nav-active');
  }
}
```

The navbar is this

```
<nav class="bg-transparent shadow-lg sticky top-0 z-50 h-[3.75rem] transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
 ...
</nav>
```

This is the applied CSS

```
.nav-active {
  @apply bg-blue-800 !important;
  box-shadow: 5px -1px 12px -5px grey;
}
.scrolltotop-active {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work and I don't have enough knowledge how to do it right. Goal is to change navbar from transparent to blue background color on scroll down 300px and show a scroll-to-top button at 600px scrolling.
What is missing here?

Comment: Could you describe what your code is supposed to do. Also show enough HTML to create a working snippet.

Comment: I have added now more code to explain better.

Comment: As far as I see, it is JavaScript problem not related to TailwindCSS, you can remove [tailwind-css] tag.

Comment: root and threshold property missing from config  object